# Trading view passing alert condition comment as data for the aler pop up

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am trying to pass last closed candle stick bar, as comment in pine script to added to the alert pop up. I have to say that I am practicing to understand properly all the functions in a strategy, my strategy for practice:

```
//@version=5


startDate = input(title="Start Date",defval=15)
startMonth = input(title="Start Month",defval=1)
startYear = input(title="Start Year",defval=2023)
afterStartDate = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone,startYear, startMonth, startDate, 0, 0))
investment = input.int(defval=1000, title='INVESTMENT USDT')
// commission = input.float(defval=0.08, title='INVESTMENT USDT')
comm=0.08


strategy('BS WAB with lines', shorttitle='WAB', overlay=true, default_qty_value = 1000, commission_type = strategy.commission.percent, commission_value = comm)
// Version 1.0
// Author: Eggsteban
// Based on the idea of @Likwid and @eggsteban 

// Definitions: Price and Timeframes
src = input(close, title='Source')
resolution = timeframe.period
price = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, resolution, src)

// Defintions: Moving Average periods and types
ma1Period = input.int(defval=8, title='Period', inline='1', group='Moving Averages: Zone 1')
ma1Type = input.string(defval='EMA', title='Type', options=['EMA', 'SMA', 'WMA', 'HMA', 'LIN'], tooltip='MA Smoothing', inline='1', group='Moving Averages: Zone 1')

ma2Period = input.int(defval=21, title='Period', inline='2', group='Moving Averages: Zone 1')
ma2Type = input.string(defval='EMA', title='Type', options=['EMA', 'SMA', 'WMA', 'HMA', 'LIN'], tooltip='MA Smoothing', inline='2', group='Moving Averages: Zone 1')


// Moving Average Calculation
ma1 = ma1Type == 'EMA' ? ta.ema(price, ma1Period) : ma1Type == 'SMA' ? ta.sma(price, ma1Period) : ma1Type == 'WMA' ? ta.wma(price, ma1Period) : ma1Type == 'HMA' ? ta.hma(price, ma1Period) : ma1Type == 'LIN' ? ta.linreg(price, ma1Period, 0) : na
ma2 = ma2Type == 'EMA' ? ta.ema(price, ma2Period) : ma2Type == 'SMA' ? ta.sma(price, ma2Period) : ma2Type == 'WMA' ? ta.wma(price, ma2Period) : ma2Type == 'HMA' ? ta.hma(price, ma2Period) : ma2Type == 'LIN' ? ta.linreg(price, ma2Period, 0) : na

// Definitions: Trends
TrendUp1() =>
    ma1 > ma2
TrendDown1() =>
    ma1 < ma2

trendColor1 = TrendUp1() ? color.green : TrendDown1() ? color.red : color.blue

p_ma1 = plot(ma1)
p_ma2 = plot(ma2)
fill(p_ma1, p_ma2, color=trendColor1)


plotshape(ma1 > ma2 and ma1[1] < ma2[1], style=shape.triangleup, color= color.rgb(59, 255, 108), size=size.small, text="B", location=location.belowbar,  title='Buy shades', offset=1)
plotshape(ma1 < ma2 and ma1[1] > ma2[1], style=shape.triangledown, color= color.rgb(255, 0, 0), size=size.small, text="S", location=location.abovebar,  title='Sell shades', offset=1)


mainComment=str.tostring(high[1])
strategyAmount=investment/close
// strategy(default_qty_type = str.tostring(investment))
longCondition = ma1 > ma2 and ma1[1] < ma2[1]
if (longCondition and afterStartDate)
    strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, qty=strategyAmount, comment = mainComment)

shortCondition = ma1 < ma2 and ma1[1] > ma2[1]
if (shortCondition and afterStartDate)
    strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short, qty=strategyAmount, comment = mainComment)
```

so the idea is that the pop up alert will display the last price of the previous candle in the pop up aler

[image: prevous price, but pop up is showing the id of the alert]

Can you please guide how to pass my strategy comment as message in the strategy alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an order comment to the alert notification, alert notification, include the `{{strategy.order.comment}}` placeholder in the alert message window:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer i have added in the alert settings the following: {
    "name":"main",
    "action": "{{strategy.order.action}}",
    "market":  "{{ticker}}",
    "orderAmt": "{{strategy.order.contracts}}",
    "price":  "{{strategy.order.price}}",
    "securityKey":"{{timenow}}",
"previousPrice":"{{strategy.order.comment}}"
}, but I am not getting the p price

Comment: [![please see the last key][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugJAt.png

Comment: Have you re-installed the alert? just tested from my side and the comment passed as expected, so the issue is not with the code. [screenshot of alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Qr1.png)

Comment: i am going to create a new alert, from scratch, and check the outcome

Comment: You are are correct, Thank you very much